# Can rsyslogd use /etc/hosts file instead of DNS?

Tags: linux, logging, centos6, rsyslog, hosts

I have a problem with rsyslogd using DNS to PTR-resolve each remote host's name.

Is there a way to use the '/etc/hosts' to do same job and disable resolution using DNS?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by ensuring the `hosts` entry in nsswitch.conf is configured as `hosts            files dns`, meaning it will look at /etc/hosts first, and then DNS.

**EDIT**: As mentionned by @ThomasN below, this impacts more than just rsyslog, and you probably want to think about that approach before picking it.

But that may not be quite right:

- if you actually want the resolution to happen, you might want to consider installing a local, caching resolver (could be dnsmasq, pdns-resolver, unbound, or any number of alternatives), and configure very long TTLs on the domains in question (if that is possible with your chosen server).
- if you don't want resolution of those domains (or not from rsyslog, at least), then you can disable DNS in two ways (using command line switches):

  1. `-Q` disables DNS lookups during ACL processing, meaning all your network ACLs will need to be `fromhost-ip`-based.
  2. `-x` disables DNS for 'remote messages' (not completely clear what that means, beyond I guess that the remote host's domain name is *not* resolved at any point).

Most people seem to end up using both these flags together, but as mentionned above, this does impact your config. 
See https://linux.die.net/man/8/rsyslogd for more

Comment: Changing `nsswitch.conf` is a global change: all host lookups from all programs will happen using that ordering. This may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasN - didn't think to clarify that - let me do it now